# How to summarize running time

Tags: bash, tcl

I want to summarize some scripts  execution time. I try to do it via tcl.
As an input I have :

```
00:00:00:09
00:00:34:05
00:00:50:34
.....
```

Input format is `<days:hours:minutes:seconds>`

How can I summarize the time and get one output as summarized output.

Output format: `<days:hours:minutes:seconds>`

Comment: What is the kind of output you're looking for? Where are the inputs stored?

Comment: I want to calculate total time. I got the execution time from .log files after running some jobs.

Comment: You have the question tagged w/ Bash, could you not use `time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a file named "durations":

```
set days [set hours [set mins [set secs 0]]]
set fh [open durations r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    scan $line %d:%d:%d:%d d h m s
    incr days $d
    incr hours $h
    incr mins $m
    incr secs $s
}
close $fh

incr mins  [expr {$secs / 60}];  set secs  [expr {$secs % 60}]
incr hours [expr {$mins / 60}];  set mins  [expr {$mins % 60}]
incr days  [expr {$hours / 24}]; set hours [expr {$hours %24}]
puts [format "%d:%02d:%02d:%02d" $days $hours $mins $secs]
```

```
0:01:24:48
```

And bash

```
while IFS=: read d h m s; do
    (( days += 10#$d, hours += 10#$h, mins += 10#$m, secs += 10#$s ))
done < durations 
(( mins += secs/60, secs %= 60 ))
(( hours += mins/60, mins %= 60 ))
(( days += hours/24, hours %= 24 ))
printf "%d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $days $hours $mins $secs
```

```
0:01:24:48
```

The `10#` in the bash while loop are to enforce base-10 interpretation of numbers with leading zero (avoid illegal octal errors for 08, 09)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "00:00:00:09
00:00:34:05
00:00:50:34" | \
awk -F ':' '
  BEGIN{s=0}
  {s += $4 + $3*60 + $2*3600 + $1*86400}
  END{
    rem = s%86400
    days = (s-rem)/86400
    s = rem

    rem = s%3600
    hours = (s-rem)/3600
    s = rem

    rem = s%60
    mins = (s-rem)/60
    s=rem

    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n", days, hours, mins, s)
  }'
```

Output:

```
00:01:24:48
```

Comment: Thank you all, 
I have used the version writing by glenn jackman with tcl,